# Want same behavior as the photo button in the SMS app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am working on a sign up page and would like to have a profile picture section where when you click the image a panel with a "Take Photo", a "Choose Photo", and a "Cancel" button slides up from the button... just like what happens when you click the little camera button while writing an SMS.

Do I have to build it all from scratch myself? Or?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for UiActionSheet.

[Here is a tutorial](http://ykyuen.wordpress.com/2010/04/14/iphone-uiactionsheet-example/) which explains how to program a uiActionSheet.

Comment: Maybe I actually am - will take a look straight away! Thanks a lot! :)